# How can I define a function that will calculate the product of the value in a dictionary and a set rate?

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

Result I'm looking for:
6.9

6.9 is the sum of 2.5 + 1 + 3 + .40. I want to write the code so that whenever I change the quantity of each coin, the variable dollar_amount will update with the correct amount.

```py
def calc_dollars(quarter, nickels, dimes, pennies):

    piggy_bank = {
        "quarters":10, #this is 10 quarters, which is 2.5
        "nickels":20, #this is 20 nickels, which is 1
        "dimes":30, #this is 30 dimes, which is 3
        "pennies":40 #this is 40 pennies, which is .40
    }

    for quarters, v in piggy_bank.items():
        quarters = v * 0.25

    for nickels, v in piggy_bank.items():
        nickels = v * 0.05

    for dimes, v in piggy_bank.items():
        dimes = v * 0.10

    for pennies, v in piggy_bank.items():
        pennies = v * 0.01

    dollar_amount = sum(quarters, nickels, dimes, pennies)

    print(dollar_amount)
```

Comment: `for quarters, v in piggy_bank.items():` this just not iterate over quarters but also nickels,dimes and pennies

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Comment: You don't need to iterate. Just get the amount for each coin and multiply by its value, and add those up. Also, `sum()` is for adding up items in a container. Just use `+` to add variables: `quarters + nickels + dimes + pennies`

Comment: The function never uses its parameters. What are they for?

Comment: The question requires clarification.  It's clear that the sum of all the coin values is required, but not what `piggy_bank` is for.  Is there a need for the number of coins in the `piggy_bank` to be updated?  As already mentioned, each `for-loop` iterates over all the keys in `piggy_bank`.

Comment: This question belongs to the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) website.

Comment: piggy_bank lists the quantity of each coin as a dictionary.

Comment: The additional instructions read: Once you have given yourself a large stash of coins in your piggy_bank, look at each key and perform the appropriate math on the integer value to determine how much money you have in dollars. Store that value in a variable named dollar_amount and print it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this:

```py
one_quarter = 0.25
one_nickel = 0.05
one_dime = 0.10
one_penny = 0.01


def calc_dollars(quarters, nickels, dimes, pennies):
    return quarters * one_quarter + nickels * one_nickel + dimes * one_dime + pennies * one_penny
```

For instance:

```
>>> calc_dollars(3, 0, 2, 5)
1.0
```

Comment: Would I still be able to use the dictionary for when I need to change the amount for each coin? piggy_bank = {"quarters":10,  "nickels":20,  "dimes":30,  "pennies":40}

Comment: @Barmar  - this worked: 
       piggy_bank = {
        "quarters":10,
        "nickels":20,
        "dimes":30,
        "pennies":40
    }
    
one_quarter = 0.25
one_nickel = 0.05
one_dime = 0.10
one_penny = 0.01


def calc_dollars(quarters, nickels, dimes, pennies):
    return quarters * one_quarter + nickels * one_nickel + dimes * one_dime + pennies * one_penny

dollar_amount = calc_dollars(10, 20, 30, 40)
print(dollar_amount)